# Is there anyway to hide some/all participant's video feed during a meeting?

Tags: zoom-meeting

As a developer I very often find myself being invited to zoom meetings that I do not control.
I personally have a need for audio only meetings with sometimes viewing a shared screen. I do not want to see other peoples faces - both on the window which has all participant tiles and in the window that shows the current speaker / shared screen. I do need to be able view a shared screen.

I am on the Free plan.

Is this available on any plan? Any plugin that can help? Something more technical / programmatic?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [Stop Incoming Video Feature](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/4409500570381-Stopping-all-incoming-video-in-a-meeting-or-webinar) which looks very promising.
This might be a new feature or I enabled something in settings to make it visible. Need to check it out.

Comment: It is indeed a recent update - https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/4408782657165-Release-notes-for-September-22-2021. I had searched high and low for this in the past